# how to find a row value of the row index matlab?

Tags: matlab, indexing, row

I have a matrix A where i found the row index with min value:

```
  [val, ind] = min (S)
```

how to get the value of this row at column 1?

The data I use in text file A:

```
dat    Y         S
100    0.86     105
 ...
20     0.4     145
```

I Find the min of S column. index the row 'ind' and need to return 'dat' column value of the correpsong row.

So e.g. S(min) = 105, [ind]=1, i need to return dat = 100.

Sorry for basic question.

Thanks

Comment: Use `out = dat(ind)`?

Comment: @Divakar. I read help on indices but still not clear. How do i get all columns of the row at 'rowindex==ind'? in case i need to work with column values: e.g. subtract and divide by certain number? Many thanks! i need something like 'out = dat/3, Y/3, S/3' so that I could work with column values (here divide by 3).

Comment: Maybe you can post that as a separate question, as it sounds entirely different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have read your textfile into the variable `A`

```
[val, ind] = min(A(:,3))
```

`ind` is now your row number.

Then you just do

```
A(ind,1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. however, i get an error.Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
What is the reason could be?

Comment: Check that `I,J` is the same size as `S`. `ind2sub` is just converting you index to a subscript.

Comment: @mil To avoid confusions, why not use a sample input-output combination in your question.

Comment: @kkuilla thanks a lot. this is helpful. however, S(ind,1) gives me 'val' which '105' not the 'dat' which should be 100. What shall i change?

Comment: Should be `A(ind,1)`. My mistake. Apologies.

Comment: @kkuilla I tried that. is gives error: Index exceeds matrix dimensions.any idea why is saying so?